# How can I handle cycles / infinite loops in recursive CTEs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, cte, recursive

Cycles in graphs lead to infinite loops in CTEs.

[Dealing with them in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31745768/4801767) is straightforward.

Since 8.0 MySQL also allows for CTEs. How I can detect cycles and infinite loops in MySQL CTEs?

The goal is not to interrupt the query after 1000 or whatever number of iterations, but to actually handle it in the code (for instance by collecting in an array the list of visited nodes and having an inequality condition to avoid loops).

Or are there any "in-built" options to deal with this, like `cycle COLNAME` in Postgres CTEs?

My current code looks something like this

```
with recursive circle as (                                                               
select friend2, name2, 0 as depth from my_view1 where friend1 = 1
union
select m.friend2, m.name2, c.depth+1 from my_view1 m
inner join circle c on c.friend2 = m.friend1)
select * from circle where circle.depth < 2;
```

The underlying tables can be created with:

```
create table people (person_id integer primary key, name varchar(20) not null);

insert into people (person_id, name) values (1, 'tom'), (2, 'dick'), (3, 'harry'), (4, 'susan'), (5, 'mary'), (6, 'jill');

create table friends (friend1 integer references people (person_id), friend2 integer references people (person_id), primary key (friend1, friend2));

insert into friends (friend1, friend2) values (1,2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6);

insert into friends (friend1, friend2) values (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (6,5);

create view my_view1 as select f.friend1, p.name as name1, f.friend2, p1.name as name2 from friends f join people p on p.person_id = f.friend1 join people p1 on p1.person_id = f.friend2 ;
```

Comment: So I guess you this rules out [cte_max_recursion_depth](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_cte_max_recursion_depth) as a system variable, and your more after the [CYCLE RESTRICT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/#cycle-restrict) kind of capabilities that MariaDB-10.5.2+ has. But I think [UNION DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-1-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes-part-four-depth-first-or-breadth-first-traversal-transitive-closure-cycle-avoidance/) is the MySQL way.

Comment: The issue is not with `cte_max_recursion_depth` - The problem is it gives an error `Recursive query aborted after 11 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.` This will never work because cycles lead to infinite loops.

Comment: @danblack *But I think UNION DISTINCT is the MySQL way.* This cannot help when CTE contains the value which is level-dependent. For example, when some column collects full path from the root. In this case we can use extensive way - collect rows `id` list and check that current `id` value is not present in it.

Comment: `UNION DISTINCT` will not work in situations where you have something like a friends circle, A is friends with B and B is friends with A.

Comment: *situations where you have something like a friends circle, A is friends with B and B is friends with A.* Collect friends list. After 2nd iteration it will contain `'A,B'`, and the condition `WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(name, collected_names)` will stop cycling.

Comment: @Akina I don't have much background in MySQL, I mostly dabble in Postgres. May I request you to help out with the statements to collect the friends list? I just posted my current code in the question.

Comment: *I just posted my current code in the question.* Please add input data (if needed, for example, this can be userid value for which you want to get friends collection) and desired output.

Comment: that's already there in the recursive query -  `where friend1 = 1` with `friend1` and `friend2` of the `friends` table being FK's to the `person_id` column in the `people` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case UNION DISTINCT in CTE is enough for to prevent cycle:

```
create table people (
  person_id integer primary key,
  name varchar(20) not null
  );
insert into people (person_id, name) values 
  (1, 'tom'), 
  (2, 'dick'),
  (3, 'harry'), 
  (4, 'susan'),
  (5, 'mary'),
  (6, 'jill');
TABLE people;
create table friends (
  friend1 integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (friend1) references people (person_id),
  friend2 integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (friend2) references people (person_id),
  primary key (friend1, friend2)
  );
insert into friends (friend1, friend2) values
  (1,2),
  (2, 3),
  (3, 4),
  (5, 6),
  (2, 1), 
  (3, 2),
  (4, 3),
  (6, 5);
TABLE friends;
```

| person_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tom |
| 2 | dick |
| 3 | harry |
| 4 | susan |
| 5 | mary |
| 6 | jill |

| friend1 | friend2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
  SELECT friend1, friend2
  FROM friends
--  WHERE friend1 = 1
  UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT cte.friend1, friends.friend2
  FROM cte
  JOIN friends ON cte.friend2 = friends.friend1
  )
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, t2.*
FROM cte
JOIN people t1 ON t1.person_id = cte.friend1
JOIN people t2 ON t2.person_id = cte.friend2
WHERE cte.friend1 <> cte.friend2
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

| person_id | name | person_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | 2 | dick |
| 1 | tom | 3 | harry |
| 1 | tom | 4 | susan |
| 2 | dick | 1 | tom |
| 2 | dick | 3 | harry |
| 2 | dick | 4 | susan |
| 3 | harry | 1 | tom |
| 3 | harry | 2 | dick |
| 3 | harry | 4 | susan |
| 4 | susan | 1 | tom |
| 4 | susan | 2 | dick |
| 4 | susan | 3 | harry |
| 5 | mary | 6 | jill |
| 6 | jill | 5 | mary |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tax35bUh)

if you need the friendship data for definite user or for a list of users then edit/uncomment the condition in base query of the CTE.

If you need to use this query as a view then add `CREATE VIEW collect_friends AS` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please show instead how to use `FIND_IN_SET` as you had mentioned in your comment to the question.

Comment: @dakini https://dbfiddle.uk/OAC1BWlX

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much! It is a very "involved" approach with `concat_ws`.

Comment: @dakini CONCAT_WS acts similarly CONCAT. But it if NULL-safe - it simply ignores NULLs whereas CONCAT returns NULL if at least one operand is NULL.